# Task set in Task Scheduler won’t run when triggered on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I tried to set up a task as simple as running a `cmd.exe` on system startup with elevated privileges. If I right click the task and select `Run`, it works just fine. But no triggers are ever fired. I tried startup and login triggers. I am also unable to create a shortcut to the task. Was that feature removed? Some old tutorials said that a shortcut to the task can be put in `Startup` folder and `Trigger` settings omitted.

Here is my exported task:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2019-10-21T00:59:35.5205959</Date>
    <Author>PC1\User1</Author>
    <URI>\cmdTask</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <BootTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </BootTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-21-2114544706-2132738194-774568325-1001</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Comment: I think you want to be sure to select/check `Run whether logged on or not` and at login and not at startup. If you are expecting to see if from Task Manager or whatever, then you want to run it at login and not startup. I assume running `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` is just for testing and the real non-test process will run and then end rather than just staying up in memory unless killed as running this job works. Again, I assume you are testing. Give that a whirl and let me know if that helps.

Comment: I tried to switch to `Run whether user is logged on or not` and it askes for password before saving settings. The username is already entered and this is my only user that is also administrator. I input the login password and I get an error saying `The specified account name is not valid`. `Cmd.exe` is only a test case, I will use it for several other executables if I can get it to work.

Comment: If running when the user is not logged on, the account used might need Logon as Batch permission

Comment: @miran80 Do you expect it to run for every user that signs onto the machine at each login or will it need to run only once and before any login occurs. You can get it to work either way but help me understand how you are expecting the processes to run. Will it run only one at logon for each account that could login or just once and it can be done before logon? Can you explain what one of the exe's will do exactly as this might be helpful as well to determine the best task scheduler configuration.

Comment: Funny enough the `Log on of any user` trigger works fine. The program is expected to run every time a computer is turned on (or in my case `any` user logs in since only that works) and it should stay running indefinitely, until user logs out or computer turns off. Only one instance of program should be running at any point. I discovered another strange behavior but might be better suited for a separated question: Basically I got some third party program for which I turned off both scheduled tasks and services but the program still turns on at startup. There's no shortcut in startup folder too.